# Trouble writing and reading image from/to internal memory on Android tablet (3.1)

Tags: android, file-io, bitmap, imageview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I thought this wouldn't be too hard but have been banging my head against a desk for the last few hours and would really appreciate some help. Essentially, I want to get an image from a url, save it to internal memory (not sd card) and be able to retrieve that image and show it using an ImageView at a later time.

This is how I get the pictures from a url and write them to memory(urls are stored in "pics"):

```
                    String urlstring = pics[l][w];
                if (urlstring != null){
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
                        InputStream input = url.openStream();
                        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(("specimage"+l) + ("" +w+".jpg"), MODE_PRIVATE);


                        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
                        int n = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        while (n >= 0) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            n = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        } 
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        GlobalState.popupMessage(homePage, "Error", "Files could not be stored on disk");
                    }
                }
```

This is how I attempt to retrieve them (path is the filename):

```
private Bitmap getPic(String path){
     FileInputStream in;
     Bitmap bMap = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        try {
            in = openFileInput(path);
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
            buf.read(bMapArray);
            bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
            if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            }
            if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("excep.");
        }
        if (bMap == null) System.out.println("null");
    return bMap;
}
```

If I do this the picture does not show up, but the program does not crash. An exception is not triggered. However, the value of bMap is given as null. I also get this strange message in the log:

DEBUG/skia(19358): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I have been ransacking my brain to no avail. 
I should mention I do setImageBitmap in the ui thread.

Comment: Can you use Log.e( ) and let us know the exact exception you are getting

Comment: I'm not getting an exception at all. It's just not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, (Replace with your) and let me know what happen,

```
ImageView  img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
FileInputStream in;
     Bitmap bMap = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        try {
            in = openFileInput("icon.png");
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
            buf.read(bMapArray);
            bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray,0,bMapArray.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            }
            if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("excep.");
        }
```

Comment: No luck. I got this message: DEBUG/skia(19639): --- decoder->decode returned false. Also bMap was again null.